# Custom tab and controls split over multiple files/features not working in subfolder in a document library

Tags: ribbon

I have a definition for a custom tab with a group with buttons for use within document libraries. One of the buttons is defined in another feature, this way i get a 'pluggable' structure for my custom tab. Buttons are made available based on the features activated (which contain the definitions for 'extra' buttons).

This system works fine, until I browse to a (sub)folder in the document library. The extra buttons is lost now, and i get an Javascript error. ("Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: element")

Even when placing all the '`CommandUIDefinition's` in one file this occurs. It seems to be connected to the '`InitialTabId`' parameter in the URL. When it is set to my new custom tab, the extra button is missing.

**This works:** Browse to documentlibrary, open a folder, switch to my customtab (all buttons are present)

**This doesn't work:** Browse to documentlibrary, switch to my customtab (all button presen), open a folder (now the button in the separate UIdefinition is missing).

Below is my Ribbon definition XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="Martijn.Ribbon"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
    RegistrationId="101"
    RegistrationType="List">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
          Location="Ribbon.LibraryContextualGroup._children"
          >
          <Tab
            Id="Martijn.Ribbon.Tab"
            Title="My Custom Tab"
            Description="This holds my custom commands!"
            Sequence="501">
            <Scaling
              Id="Martijn.Ribbon.Tab.Scaling">
              <MaxSize
                Id="Martijn.Ribbon.Tab.MaxSize"
                GroupId="Martijn.Ribbon.Tab.Group"
                Size="OneLargeTwoMedium"/>
              <Scale
                Id="Martijn.Ribbon.Tab.Scaling.CustomTabScaling"
                GroupId="Martijn.Ribbon.Tab.Group"
                Size="OneLargeTwoMedium" />
            </Scaling>
            <Groups Id="Martijn.Ribbon.Tab.Groups">
              <Group
                Id="Martijn.Ribbon.Tab.Group"
                Description="This is a custom group!"
                Title="Custom Group"
                Sequence="52"
                Template="Martijn.Ribbon.Templates.CustomTemplateExample">
                <Controls Id="Martijn.Ribbon.Tab.Group.Controls">
                  <Button
                    Id="Martijn.Ribbon.Tab.Group.HelloWorld"
                    Command="Martijn.Command.HelloWorldCommand"
                    Sequence="15"
                    Description="Says Hello to the World!"
                    LabelText="Hello, World!"
                    TemplateAlias="cust1"/>
                </Controls>
              </Group>
            </Groups>
          </Tab>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Martijn.Ribbon.Tab.Group.Controls._children">

          <Button
            Id="Martijn.Ribbon.Tab.Group.GoodbyeWorld"
            Command="Martijn.Command.GoodbyeWorldCommand"
            Sequence="17"
            Description="Says Good-bye to the World!"
            LabelText="Good-bye, World!"
            TemplateAlias="cust2"/>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
          <GroupTemplate Id="Martijn.Ribbon.Templates.CustomTemplateExample">
            <Layout
              Title="OneLargeTwoMedium"
              LayoutTitle="OneLargeTwoMedium">
              <Section Alignment="Top" Type="OneRow">
                <Row>
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="cust1" />
                </Row>
              </Section>
              <Section Alignment="Top" Type="TwoRow">
                <Row>
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Medium" TemplateAlias="cust2" />
                </Row>
                <Row>
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Medium" TemplateAlias="cust3" />
                </Row>
              </Section>
            </Layout>
          </GroupTemplate>
        </CommandUIDefinition>

      </CommandUIDefinitions>

      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
          Command="Martijn.Command.HelloWorldCommand"
          CommandAction="javascript:alert('Hello, world!');" />
        <CommandUIHandler
          Command="Martijn.Command.GoodbyeWorldCommand"
          CommandAction="javascript:alert('Good-bye, world!');" />
        <CommandUIHandler
          Command="Martijn.Command.LoveWorldCommand"
          CommandAction="javascript:alert('I love you, world!');" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```